# BeautifulSoup Parses HTML as 1 Line String

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For some reason, when I use beautifulsoup to parse an HTML page, and print the page to a txt file, it unformats the html and puts it on 1 line. When I try to search using regex, it finds something and then prints out the line, this however prints out the whole page because it's all 1 line... How can I get it to stop doing this?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib.request


def main():
    #Open the PID file and read the PID's
    URLList = []
    PID = [open("PID.txt").read().split()]
    for list in PID:
        for code in list:
            URLList.append("http://www.abb.com/productdetails/" + code)
    pageNo = 1
    for URL in URLList:
        fh = open("html.txt", "a")
        fh.write("\n\n\n\n\n")
        webPage = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage.read())
        print("Page", pageNo, "retrieved")
        fh.write(str(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8")))
        pageNo += 1
    fh.close()
    output = open('html.txt', 'r')
    for line in output:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if re.search('NetDepth', line):
            print(line)


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Basically, what I need it to do is open a file of UPC's/PID's and go to the website they're from and open their pages... That part works fine. I then want to gt the HTML and put it all in a txt file. From there, I would like to search that file for certain elements such as a div tag or a ProductNetDepth id. The problem is that when it finds one of those things, it prints the whole document since it thinks it is one line. I just wanted the HTML line that had that in it.

Here is just a bit of what the source code looks like for the website:

```
        <div class="Dimensions pisEvenRow">

                                                                        <div id="ProductNetLength" class="detailPageLeftColumn">
                        Product Net Length:
                                  </div>

                    <div class="detailPageRightColumn">

                                    <div>68 mm</div>
                                                                                                  </div>
            </div>
        <div class="Dimensions pisOddRow">

                                                                        <div id="ProductNetDepth" title="Depth of a single unpacked product" class="detailPageLeftColumn">Product Net Depth:</div>

                    <div class="detailPageRightColumn">

                                    <div>67.5 mm</div>
                                                                                                  </div>
            </div>
        <div class="Dimensions pisEvenRowLast">

                                                                        <div id="ProductNetWeight" title="Weight of a single unpacked product" class="detailPageLeftColumn">Product Net Weight:</div>

                    <div class="detailPageRightColumn">

                                    <div>0.041 kg</div>
                                                                                                  </div>
```

Here is what it looks like after being written to the file from beautifulsoup:

```
ijQoI5DAFDwZHYnHo-npjlC99WMTQ6qWYJ8fkDP8ddGyBe9DZa4IVC3j3aFtg7m85t7V9lKauOCgTq5CZ7cJneFTTH12Nx8mLxeKkAmLee2awza0rGQucVII-WdAyptFtKvKDBSLWhBUFTU7WLzD7DN4tAZzUEbQDGL2VHY5A0&amp;t=635706797508895128"/>\xc2\xa0Loading Images..\r\n                </div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class="pisDetailPageTitle">General Information</div>\n<div class="pisOddRow">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn">\n<span>Extended Product Type:\r\n      </span>\n</div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\r\n                                  E213-25-001\r\n                  </div>\n</div>\n<div class="pisEvenRow">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn">\n<span>Product ID:\r\n      </span>\n</div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\r\n                                  2CCA703041R0001\r\n                  </div>\n</div>\n<div class="pisOddRow">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn">\n<span>EAN:\r\n      </span>\n</div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\r\n                                  7612270938711\r\n                  </div>\n</div>\n<div class="pisEvenRow">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn">\n<span>Catalog Description:\r\n      </span>\n</div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\r\n                                  E213-25-10 Change over switch 25A 1CO 250VAC\r\n                  </div>\n</div>\n<div class="pisOddRowLast">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn">\n<span>Long Description:\r\n      </span>\n</div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\r\n                                  Change over switches according DIN EN 60669-1, VDE 0632 Part 1, Rated currents: 16/25 A, 250 VACPDC, Contacts: 1 CO/2 CO, Module width: 0,5/1\r\n                  </div>\n</div>\n<div class="pisDetailPageTitle">\r\n      Categories\r\n      </div>\n<div class="pisEvenRowLast" id="pisEvenRowLast">\n<ul class="pisCategoryList">\n<span>Products</span><span class="CategorySeperator">\xc2\xbb</span>\n<li>                      Low Voltage Products and Systems\r\n                      </li>\n<span class="CategorySeperator">\xc2\xbb</span>\n<li>                      Modular DIN Rail Products\r\n                      </li>\n<span class="CategorySeperator">\xc2\xbb</span>\n<li>                      Modular DIN Rail Components MDRCs\r\n                      </li>\n<span class="CategorySeperator">\xc2\xbb</span>\n<li>                      Command Devices\r\n                      </li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n<div class="displayNone" id="PisDiv_PlaceHolder1">\xc2\xa0</div>\n<div class="pisDetailPageTitle" id="Ordering">Ordering</div>\n<div class="Ordering pisOddRow">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn" id="Ean">\r\n                            EAN:\r\n                                      </div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\n<div>7612270938711</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class="Ordering pisEvenRow">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn" id="MinimumOrderQuantity">\r\n                            Minimum Order Quantity:\r\n                                      </div>\n<div class="detailPageRightColumn">\n<div>10 piece</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class="Ordering pisOddRowLast">\n<div class="detailPageLeftColumn" id="CustomsTariffNumber">\r\n                            Customs Tariff Number:\r\n
```

If you could help, that would be great... I've tried everything from prettify to trying to split it into lines myself, but nothing seems to work correctly. I would like it to be formatted like the source code so that I can easily search and get the items I need from it! Thanks for the help, and if you can, don't just give me an answer, could you explain what you did too!

Comment: The `\r\n` look kind of like they're meant to be line breaks.

Comment: Nick, can you give me one url, so I see it for myself?

Comment: By the way, why are you using regexes to search for things, when soup will do it for you?

Comment: Here is a URL, and the reason I am using regexes is because I thought it would be easier to get it into a text file first... Is soup a better way to do it? Here is the url: http://www.abb.com/productdetails/ABB2CCA703041R0001

Comment: @Nick, soup.prettify() is working fine.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ataLRGe4

Comment: Hmmm... Could you take a look at my code? I thought I used prettify right, but it didn't seem to do anything... Let me know if I need to make any changes!

Comment: @Nick you should `@RishavKundu` me so that I get notified :p

Comment: You shouldn't name your list as `list`. `list is a python keyword.

Comment: @ssundarraj Thanks for the advice... I will name it something more helpful and less confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this simple script to extract the `NetDepth` and it worked fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib import urlopen

soup = bs(urlopen('<insert url here>').read())
print soup.find(id="ProductNetDepth").next_sibling.next_sibling.div.text
```

If you look at the structure of the html, the div containing the mm measurement is the sibling of the div with an id of ProductNetDepth. So I just built on that.

If you’re not familiar with soup’s searching functions, then you should see  their extremely well written [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Thank you very much for this... I got it working now! Would this also work if there were multiple ProductNetDepth's in the document?

Comment: @Nick, no, there can only be one element with a given ID.

Comment: Oh yeah... I was thinking of HTML classes for some reason... Thank yo very much again for the answer!

Comment: @Nick no problem. Do read the soup documentation though. It is very nicely written and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different possible solutions to your problem here, but I'm going to demonstrate the simplest.

First, I'm going to go over the problem statement and your solution.

**Problem statement:** Print all lines of request HTML pages that contain a certain phrase (in this case, "NetDepth").

**Attempted solution:** You're using `urllib` to request the HTML file, then trying to use BeautifulSoup to prettify it, writing it to a text file, then finally opening the text file and using regex to pull specific lines that contain the matched regex.

In my opinion, this solution is kind of heavy handed for what we really need here. There is no reason we really need to write the HTML to a file and then read it again from the file. We can just deal with the contents of the HTML while looping through PIDs and making HTTP requests. Also, other than "prettify", we're not really using BeautifulSoup's basic functionality, which is to parse HTML for specific tags (which it does amazingly, btw). With both of those things in mind, here's the proposed solution...

**Proposed solution:** Use `requests` to GET the HTML page, parse the contents of that page line by line, and run regex on each line to find lines that meet the criteria.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import requests

def main():
    #Open the PID file and read the PID's
    URLList = []
    PID = [open("PID.txt").read().split()]
    for list in PID:
        for code in list:
            URLList.append("http://www.abb.com/productdetails/" + code)
    pageNo = 1

    for URL in URLList:
        response = requests.get(url=URL)

        for line in response.iter_lines():
            line = str(line.rstrip())
            if re.search('NetDepth', line):
                print(line)
```

Remember [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "Simple is better than complex"